# How to make a Java Swing app always stay on back

Tags: java, swing

I'm doing a widget, kind of like Windows 7 Gadgets, and I want it to always be on the back. It always needs to be on the desktop, so when the user goes there it'll be there.

I'm looking for the opposite of setAlwaysOnTop, I need something that checks when the user goes to the desktop but I haven't found how.

I'm using a JDialog instead of a JFrame to hide the app icon from the taskbar, just to clarify.

Comment: `setAlwaysOnTop(false);` will do this

Comment: @ELITE No, that only sets it not to always stay on top, so it could be on the back, on top or between them.

Answer (score 1):

As I know about "Windows 7 Gadgets" they only remain on desktop rather than on top of any open window. If you use "setAlwaysOnTop", it will put you widget on top of any application whether it is Chrome or Eclipse IDE.
Now for the widget position on desktop, you should do these things:

1. Get the size of the screen and size of widget in runtime thread(is user drags the widget on desktop)
2. Find position of widget on window screen.
3. Update the position of widget as per mouse pointer location (you have to do some math to calculate it)

Also you can remove title bar and borders from the JDialog to give it a widget view.

Hope this will help. :-)

Comment: I've already done all of that, the issue I have is that I don't know how to make the JDialog always stay on the back, by back I mean on the desktop.

Comment: I've tried with dialog.toBack(), which works but I don't know how to check when the user goes to the desktop to apply the toBack method.

Comment: Without the minimum code, cannot say much. So post at least minimum working code.